# Find in Double Nested Array MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have this Collection in mongodb

```
{
"_id" : "777",
"someKey" : "someValue",
"someArray" : [
    {
        "name" : "name1",
        "someNestedArray" : [
            {
                "name" : "value"
            },
            {
                "name" : "delete me"
            }
        ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to find document based on someArray.someNestedArray.name
but i can't find any useful link all search result about update nested array
i am trying this but return nothing

```
db.mycollection.find({"someArray.$.someNestedArray":{"$elemMatch":{"name":"1"}}})
db.mycollection.find({"someArray.$.someNestedArray.$.name":"1"})
```

and Some thing else

how can i find by element in double nested array mongodb?

Answer (score 85, accepted):

In the simplest sense this just follows the basic form of ["dot notation"](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#dot-notation) as used by MongoDB. That will work regardless of which array member the inner array member is in, as long as it matches a value:

```js
db.mycollection.find({
    "someArray.someNestedArray.name": "value"
})
```

That is fine for a "single field" value, for matching multiple-fields you would use [`$elemMatch`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/):

```js
db.mycollection.find({
    "someArray": { 
        "$elemMatch": {
            "name": "name1",
            "someNestedArray": {
                "$elemMatch": {
                    "name": "value",
                    "otherField": 1
                }
            }
        }
    }
})
```

That matches the document which would contain something with a a field at that "path" matching the value. If you intended to "match and filter" the result so only the matched element was returned, this is not possible with the positional operator projection, [as quoted](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/#nested-arrays):

> **Nested Arrays**
>
> The positional $ operator cannot be used for queries which traverse more than one array, such as queries that traverse arrays nested within other arrays, because the replacement for the $ placeholder is a single value

### Modern MongoDB

We can do this by applying [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) and [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) here. The `$map` is really needed because the "inner" array can change as a result of the "filtering", and the "outer" array of course does not match the conditions when the "inner" was stripped of all elements.

Again following the example of actually having multiple properties to match within each array:

```js
db.mycollection.aggregate([
  { "$match": {
    "someArray": {
      "$elemMatch": {
         "name": "name1",
         "someNestedArray": {
           "$elemMatch": {
             "name": "value",
             "otherField": 1
           }
         }
       }
    }
  }},
  { "$addFields": {
    "someArray": {
      "$filter": {
        "input": {
          "$map": {
            "input": "$someArray",
            "as": "sa",
            "in": {
              "name": "$$sa.name",
              "someNestedArray": {
                "$filter": {
                  "input": "$$sa.someNestedArray",
                  "as": "sn",
                  "cond": {
                    "$and": [
                      { "$eq": [ "$$sn.name", "value" ] },
                      { "$eq": [ "$$sn.otherField", 1 ] }
                    ]
                  }
                }
              }             
            }
          },
        },
        "as": "sa",
        "cond": {
          "$and": [
            { "$eq": [ "$$sa.name", "name1" ] },
            { "$gt": [ { "$size": "$$sa.someNestedArray" }, 0 ] }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

Therefore on the "outer" array the [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) actually looks at the [`$size`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/) of the "inner" array after it was "filtered" itself, so you can reject those results when the whole inner array does in fact match noting.

### Older MongoDB

In order to "project" only the matched element, you need the [`.aggregate()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) method:

```js
db.mycollection.aggregate([
    // Match possible documents
    { "$match": {
        "someArray.someNestedArray.name": "value"
    }},

    // Unwind each array
    { "$unwind": "$someArray" },
    { "$unwind": "$someArray.someNestedArray" },

    // Filter just the matching elements
    { "$match": {
        "someArray.someNestedArray.name": "value"
    }},

    // Group to inner array
    { "$group": {
        "_id": { 
            "_id": "$_id", 
            "name": "$someArray.name"
        },
        "someKey": { "$first": "$someKey" },
        "someNestedArray": { "$push": "$someArray.someNestedArray" }
    }},

    // Group to outer array
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id._id",
        "someKey": { "$first": "$someKey" },
        "someArray": { "$push": {
            "name": "$_id.name",
            "someNestedArray": "$someNestedArray"
        }}
    }} 
])
```

That allows you to "filter" the matches in nested arrays for one or more results within the document.

Comment: Thanks, **That is fine for a "single field" value, for matching multiple-fields you would use `$elemMatch`** this line clarified me the exact use of `elemMatch`,

Comment: Your answer is a game changer for my project!

Answer (score 6):

You can also try something like below:

```
db.collection.aggregate(
    { $unwind: '$someArray' },
    {
        $project: {
            'filteredValue': {
                $filter: {
                  input: "$someArray.someNestedArray",
                  as: "someObj",
                  cond: { $eq: [ '$$someObj.name', 'delete me' ] }
                }
            }
        }
    }
)
```

Comment: Thanks, Life saviour!!!