# Group array after unwind and match

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have a twice nested schema:

```
mongoose.model('Team', mongoose.Schema(
{
 players : [{ 
    trikots : [{
        isNew : Boolean,
        color : String
    }]
 }]
})
```

For now, my query looks like this:

```
Team.aggregate()
        .match({'_id' : new ObjectId(teamId)})
        .unwind('players')
        .unwind('players.trikots')
        .match({'players.trikots.isNew' : 'red', 'players.trikots.isNew' : true})
        .exec(sendBack);
```

But I would like to have one Team object, that contains all players as an array. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use `Group` on `_id` with [`$push`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/) operator to return all players into an array.

```
Team.aggregate()
        .match({'_id' : new ObjectId(teamId)})
        .unwind('players')
        .unwind('players.trikots')
        .match({'players.trikots.color' : 'red', 'players.trikots.isNew' : true})
        .group({'_id':'$_id','players': {'$push': '$players'}})
        .exec(sendBack);
```

If you want any other field to be included in the final doucment add it to `_id` field during group operation.

```
.group({'_id':{'_id':'$_id','some_other_field':'$some_other_field'},'players': {'$push': '$players'}})
```

Comment: Error: "the group aggregate field 'id' must be defined as an expression inside an object"

Comment: Oh sorry, my bad it should be `_id` not `id`.

Comment: If you want any other field from your original team object just add it to the `_id` in group stage. I am not sure what other field you are missing, Can you edit your question to include the output document you want?

Comment: Nice answer. Is there a way to also get the matching element as well?

Comment: @Justin have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29072062/2745704).