# mongodb filter on array inside array

Tags: mongodb, nosql, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

In my mongodb document, I have array inside array & I want to put filter on it in projection.

Sample Document:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a3ba402cc96937e91e2861d"),
    "id" : 1,
    "name" : "a",
    "var" : [ 
        {
            "id" : 11,
            "name" : "aa",
            "data" : [ 
                {
                    "type" : 1,
                    "value" : "A"
                }, 
                {
                    "type" : 2,
                    "value" : "B"
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "id" : 12,
            "name" : "ab",
            "data" : [ 
                {
                    "type" : 26,
                    "value" : "Z"
                }, 
                {
                    "type" : 10,
                    "value" : "J"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

When I run following query,

```
db.harshit.aggregate([{
    $match: { "id" : 1}
}, {
    $project: {
        "_id" : 1,
        "id" : 1,
        "name" : 1,
        "var" : {
            $filter: {
                input: "$var",
                as: "var1",
                cond: {
                    "$eq": ["$$var1.id", 12]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
])
```

then it gives expected result

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a3ba402cc96937e91e2861d"),
    "id" : 1,
    "name" : "a"
    "var" : [ 
        {
            "id" : 12,
            "name" : "ab",
            "data" : [ 
                {
                    "type" : 26,
                    "value" : "Z"
                }, 
                {
                    "type" : 10,
                    "value" : "J"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

but if I use following query

```
db.harshit.aggregate([{
    $match: { "id" : 1}
}, {
    $project: {
        "_id" : 1,
        "id" : 1,
        "name" : 1,
        "var" : {
            $filter: {
                input: "$var",
                as: "var1",
                cond: {
                    "$eq": ["$$var1.data.type", 26]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
])
```

then it gives empty array for "var"

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a3ba402cc96937e91e2861d"),
    "id" : 1,
    "name" : "a"
    "var" : []
}
```

I want to put filter on nested array "var.data" and want to project the objects that match the condition.

How do I filter those nested arrays?

Comment: Use $in instead of $eq and switch the operands. Something  like `"$in": [26, "$$var1.data.type"]`. It should filter outer array when there is a  matching condition in inner array.. You can use [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29071748/2683814) for filtering the inner array.

Comment: `"$in": [26, "$$var1.data.type"]`  gives error: invalid operator '$in'

Comment: It looks like you are not on 3.4. For lower versions try `$setIsSubset: [[26], "$$var1.data.type"]` instead.

Comment: it works perfect using the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29071748/find-in-double-nested-array-mongodb) that you provided, thanks.

Comment: `$setIsSubset: [[26], "$$var1.data.type"]` also works perfectly and it's easier than above solution. Now I am confused which one to use?

Comment: These are two different solutions. One provided in comment filters the outer array based on condition ok inner arrays and the other solution linked filters both inner and outer arrays. It looks like you are looking for first one.