# How can I search a specific data in an array inside of a mongoose database?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

```
var campgroundSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    likey:{
        numOfLikeys:{
            type:Number,
            default:0
        },
        whoLiked:[{
            id:{
                type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                ref:"User"
            },
            username:String
        }]
    }
});
```

I want to search for "username" inside of the whoLiked array.
I tried this:
Campground.find({ likey.whoLiked.username: req.user.username }, ...);

Comment: put double quotes around `"likey.whoLiked.username"`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find in Double Nested Array MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29071748/find-in-double-nested-array-mongodb)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be:

`Campground.find({ "likey.whoLiked.username": req.user.username })`

Where "likey.whoLiked.username" is wrapped as string to indicate the entire search path.

Make sure `req.user.username` is an actual valid value as well.