# Query on 3rd level nested array with array of objects in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to query on the 3rd level nested array of objects using mongodb first and then want to implement the same with mongoose.
In the below json which is stored as a document, I want to fetch the document which have products metadata with {"value" : "abc"}.

As the below json is containing nested multiple arrays so I am not able to find the right solution for it.

```
{
    "_id" : "12341234",
   "products" : [ 
        {
            "productCode" : "P05-02",
            "type" : "XX",
            "metaData" : [ 
                  [ 
                    {
                        "keyName" : "CUS_NME",
                        "isPrimary" : false,
                        "displayName" : "Customer Name",
                        "value" : "abc"
                    },
                   {
                        "keyName" : "CUS_DOB",
                        "isPrimary" : true,
                        "displayName" : "Customer DOB",   
                    }
                  ],
                  [ 
                    {
                        "keyName" : "CUS_NME",
                        "isPrimary" : false,
                        "displayName" : "Customer Name",
                        "value" : "xyz"
                    },
                   {
                        "keyName" : "CUS_DOB",
                        "isPrimary" : true,
                        "displayName" : "Customer DOB",
                    }
                  ]
                 ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: what should be the expected output?

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet   there can be multiple documents with same json format, so I want to query on the "value" property which is inside the metadata of products. Output should be the documents with matched "value"

Comment: `db.collection.find({ "products.metaData.value": "abc" })` ???

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29071748/find-in-double-nested-array-mongodb