# Querying String Length in a Nested Array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

The json that I'm returning looks like this:

```
{
  "_id" : "id",
  "_class" : "ClassName",
  "key" : [ 
    {
      "_id" : "keyId",
      "array" : [ 
        {
          "arrKey" : "value"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm trying to query based on the `key.array.arrKey[0].value.length()`? The array should always only have one value.

I'm not sure if I need to do a find or aggregate and match, but below is my attempt at doing this query.

```
var cursor = db.getCollection('collection').find( {
    key.array.arrKey[0].value.length: {$gt: 5} 
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find in Double Nested Array MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29071748/find-in-double-nested-array-mongodb)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`$strLenCP`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/strLenCP/) within [`$expr`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/) and some careful handling of processing through arrays:

```
db.collection.find({
  "$expr": {
    "$anyElementTrue": {
      "$map": {
        "input": {
          "$reduce": {
            "input": "$key.array.arrKey",
            "initialValue": [],
            "in": { "$concatArrays": [ "$$value", "$$this" ] }
          }
        },
        "in": { "$gte": [ { "$strLenCP": "$$this" }, 5 ] }
      }
    }
  }
})
```

If you have a MongoDB older than 3.6 you can use [`$where`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/where/) instead:

```
db.collection.find({
  "$where": function() {
     return this.key.reduce((o,e) => o.concat(e.array.map(a => a.arrKey)), [])
       .some(e => e.length >= 5);
  }
})
```

Both follow the same principal of accessing the inner array elements by "concatenating" into a single array of strings, then testing those elements to see if they matched the length requirements.

---

### The following is to deter incorrect responses

**NOTE**: Before anyone else jumps on here and says *"Hey, can't you just do this:"*

```
db.collection.find({
  "$expr": { "$gte": [ { "$strLenCP": "$key.array.arrKey" }, 5 ] }
})
```

Then ***NO, you cannot***, and the reason very simply is to look at what that *aggregation expression notation actually does*:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$project": {
    "value": "$key.array.arrKey"
  }}
])
```

Returns:

```
{ "_id" : "id", "value" : [ [ "value" ] ] }
```

So the returned value of `"$key.array.arrKey"` is NOT the "string" of `"value"` but is instead the nested array as shown above. Hence the *reduce* and *array concatenation* to a single array of strings, and then the *map* operation over those array elements to test *each element*.

That is why both the aggregation expression *AND* the JavaScript expression follow the same logic pattern. Since `"$key.array.arrKey"` sees a completely different picture to what `.find({ "key.array.arrKey": { "$exists: true } })` might do things.

Aggregation expressions and *query operators* work ***very differently***.

> Noting of course that looking for strings longer than `6` ( or any length longer than the actual string ):
>
> ```
>  db.collection.find({
>    "$expr": { "$gte": [ { "$strLenCP": "$key.array.arrKey" }, 6 ] }
>  })
> ```
>
> would return the supplied document in the question **in error**.
>
> Note also that in this case the [`$strLenCP`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/strLenCP/) is actually comparing the "stringified" notation of the array, including the brackets `[]` and spacing. Which is of course incorrect.