# How to model a document in mongoDB- flat vs nested

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb

Hi and thanks for helping.
I need to insert data to a MongoDB collection and I confused, which approached is better, nested or flat way.

For example:
one nested document

```
{ 
   a: [ {
     aName: 'name',
     b: [ {
       bName: 'name'
     } ]
}
```

or many flat and small documents

```
{
  a: 'name',
  b: 'name'
}
```

Comments:

- there isn't update query, just insert (and get)
- the nested object is not huge (not overflow the limit)

my thinks for the nested way:

- it's more verbose, its help to the next person that looking on the collection to understand the hierarchy
- the get is simpler, and the code for get is more readable

my thinks for the flat way:

- maybe in the future should do more aggregeation on the collection, it will be easier.

Comment: The approach really depends on your application's use case. As this is too subjective I suggest you come back with more concrete problem.

Comment: I know my case as I wrote, in general, but I think there is a best practice and what not to do.

Comment: There are always exceptions, best practice is a guideline not a mandate

Comment: The question really is to general and "best practice" is really about *"how you need to use the data"*. You can see [Updating a Nested Array with MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23577123/2313887) for more information of difficulties and *general* structural advice. Also [Find in Double Nested Array MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29071748/2313887) demonstrates difficulties in the query side. Most importantly there are *"shades"* here as you probably don't really mean "flat", but you also don't want "deeply nested".