# Using $elemMatch and $or to implement a fallback logic (in projection)

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

```
db.projects.findOne({"_id": "5CmYdmu2Aanva3ZAy"},
{
  "responses": {
    "$elemMatch": {
      "match.nlu": {
        "$elemMatch": {
          "intent": "intent1",
          "$and": [
            {
              "$or": [
                {
                  "entities.entity": "entity1",
                  "entities.value": "value1"
                },
                {
                  "entities.entity": "entity1",
                  "entities.value": {
                    "$exists": false
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          ],
          "entities.1": {
            "$exists": false
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
```

In a given `project` I need a projection containing only one response, hence `$elemMatch`. Ideally, look for an exact match:

```
{
    "entities.entity": "entity1",
    "entities.value": "value1"
}
```

But if such a match doesn't exist, look for a record where `entities.value` does not exist

The query above doesn't work because if it finds an item with `entities.value` not set it will return it. How can I get this fallback logic in a Mongo query

Here is an example of document

```
{
    "_id": "5CmYdmu2Aanva3ZAy",
    "responses": [  
      {
        "match": {
          "nlu": [
            {
              "entities": [],
              "intent": "intent1"
            }
          ]
        },
        "key": "utter_intent1_p3vE6O_XsT"
      },
      {
        "match": {
          "nlu": [
            {
              "entities": [{
                  "entity": "entity1",
                  "value": "value1"
                }],
              "intent": "intent1"
            }
          ]
        },
        "key": "utter_intent1_p3vE6O_XsT"
      },
      {
        "match": {
          "nlu": [
            {
              "intent": "intent2",
              "entities": []
            },
            {
              "intent": "intent1",
              "entities": [
                {
                  "entity": "entity1"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        "key": "utter_intent2_Laag5aDZv2"
      }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Show what an actual document looks like and what you expect to receive in response. If you have different cases, then show different documents and the different expected responses.

Comment: @NeilLunn absolutely. Question updated

Comment: Hi @NeilLunn, thank you so much for your answer. I took a couple of days offs, hence the delay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the question, the first thing to start with is that doing what you want is not as simple as an [`$elemMatch`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/) projection and requires special projection logic of the aggregation framework. The second main principle here is *"nesting arrays is a **really bad idea**"*, and this is exactly why:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$match": {  "_id": "5CmYdmu2Aanva3ZAy"  } },
  { "$addFields": {
    "responses": {
      "$filter": {
        "input": {
          "$map": {
            "input": "$responses",
            "in": {
              "match": {
                "nlu": {
                  "$filter": {
                    "input": {
                      "$map": {
                        "input": "$$this.match.nlu",
                        "in": {
                          "entities": {
                            "$let": {
                              "vars": {
                                "entities": {
                                  "$filter": {
                                    "input": "$$this.entities",
                                    "cond": {
                                      "$and": [
                                        { "$eq": [ "$$this.entity", "entity1" ] },
                                        { "$or": [
                                          { "$eq": [ "$$this.value", "value1" ] },
                                          { "$ifNull": [ "$$this.value", false ] }
                                        ]}
                                      ]
                                    }
                                  }
                                }
                              },
                              "in": {
                                "$cond": {
                                  "if": { "$gt": [{ "$size": "$$entities" }, 1] },
                                  "then": {
                                    "$slice": [
                                      { "$filter": {
                                        "input": "$$entities",
                                        "cond": { "$eq": [ "$$this.value", "value1" ] }
                                      }},
                                      0
                                    ]
                                  },
                                  "else": "$$entities"
                                }
                              }
                            }
                          },
                          "intent": "$$this.intent"
                        }
                      }
                    },
                    "cond": { "$ne": [ "$$this.entities", [] ] }
                  }
                }
              },
              "key": "$$this.key"
            }
          }
        },
        "cond": { "$ne": [ "$$this.match.nlu", [] ] }
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

Will return:

```
{
  "_id" : "5CmYdmu2Aanva3ZAy",
  "responses" : [
    {
      "match" : {
        "nlu" : [
          {
            "entities" : [
              {
                      "entity" : "entity1",
                      "value" : "value1"
              }
            ],
            "intent" : "intent1"
          }
        ]
      },
      "key" : "utter_intent1_p3vE6O_XsT"
    }
  ]
}
```

That is extracting ( as best I can determine your specification ), the ***first*** matching element from the *nested inner array* of `entities` where the conditions for both `entity` and `value` are met **OR** where the `value` property does not exist.

Note the *additional fallback* in that if *both* conditions meant returning multiple array elements, then only the first match where the `value` was present and matching would be the result returned.

Querying deeply nested arrays requires chained usage of [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) and [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) in order to traverse those array contents and return only items which match the conditions. You cannot specify these conditions in an [`$elemMatch`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/) projection, nor has it even been possible until recent releases of MongoDB to even *atomically update* such structures without overwriting significant parts of the document or introducing problems with update concurrency.

More detailed explanation of this is on my existing answer to [Updating a Nested Array with MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23577266/2313887) and from the query side on [Find in Double Nested Array MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29071748/find-in-double-nested-array-mongodb).

Note that both responses there show usage of [`$elemMatch`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) as a "query" operator, which is really only about *"document selection"* ( therefore does not apply to an `_id` match condition ) and cannot be used in concert with the former "projection" variant nor the [positional `$`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/) projection operator.

You would be advised then to *"not nest arrays"* and instead take the option of *"flatter"* data structures as those answers already discuss at length.

Comment: I figured that I would have to use the aggregation framework. I realized that I could simplify it a bit by assuming that responses with more entity values sets are preferred. Using a reduce and a group steps, sorting by count and taking the first value works withou
- unwind responses and responses.match.nlu
- match entities and entities values (this returns all matching entities, with or without value)
- project->reduce: a new field containing an array with all entities values
- sort and group (with first) to select the best response.
It ends up being readable .

Comment: However I am wondering about the performance impact of unwinding at the beginning.
Thank you so much for your detailed answer and recommendations

Comment: @znat The performance is generally terrible with `$unwind` and that basically scales to get worse over sharded clusters. The basic concept here is nothing that you actually asked for needs to "group" on something "inside" the array content, nor across "multiple documents" and is indeed a "per document" operation. In that case, even though this "looks" more complicated than you think it need be, it really is not. Anyhow the ***real lesson*** here "should" be **do not nest arrays**. I know you "think" this is how you do relational structure, but it really isn't. I made the same mistakes.

Comment: I realize the limitations of nested arrays. But I have to live with them for a while until we refactor our data model