# Mongoose Schema RESTfull API and getone

Tags: express, mongoose, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate, mongoosastic

Hi i need create RESTfull API with mongoose  and express for fetch data of hotels data and i have a problem. let me show you. 
I need create this schema of DB.

```
 {
"hotels" : [{

"name" : "Hotel Emperador",
"stars" : "3",
"images" :[....],
"price" : "1596",
},
...]

}`
```

I am using mongoose and i created this schema

```
const hotelSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    hotels:[{
    id : Number,
    name: String,
    stars: String,
    images: [String],
    price: String
    }]
  });

  const hotel = mongoose.model('hotel', hotelSchema);
```

I used hotel.save() method for save this

```
const hotels = new hotel( {hotels:[{
    "name" : "Hotel Emperador",
    "stars" : "5",
    "images" :['https://media-cdn.tripadvisor.com/media/photo-s/03/01/e7/a1/hotel-bolivar.jpg'],
    "price" : "1596"
    },...]
```

the question is the schema above is ok for my requirement of data base? on mongo Atlas show this:

[image: mongoatlas]

Well my main issue is because when i run this code do not obtain the array hotels

```
 hotel.find({},function(err,result){
        if(err){
            console.log(err)
        } else {
            console.log(result)
               }
```

i get this( console.log(result) and this has sense because i have an array before my object hotels.

```
[
  {
    _id: 5ee30d871e42964f0f3b3a10,
    hotels: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ],
    __v: 0
  }
]
```

I needed do something how this for get all my nested objects inside the array

```
 hotel.findOne({ _id:"5ee30d871e42964f0f3b3a10"},function(err,result){
        if(err){
            console.log(err)
        } else {
            console.log(result)
               }
```

And here i need you help beacuse  i cant find one method for get One hotel inside my array can you help me? i need the way for obtein with mongose a response how this

```
{
"name" : "Hotel Emperador",
"stars" : "3",
"images" :[....],
"price" : "1596",
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find in Double Nested Array MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29071748/find-in-double-nested-array-mongodb)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are storing all your hotel objects a single `hotel` document. To achieve the behaviour you want with ease, you can modify your schema as follows:

```
const HotelSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    stars: String,
    images: [String],
    price: String
});
const Hotel = mongoose.model('hotel', HotelSchema);
```

To insert your list of hotels to the collection:

```
await Hotel.create([{
    "name" : "Hotel Emperador",
    "stars" : "5",
    "images" :['https://media-cdn.tripadvisor.com/media/photo-s/03/01/e7/a1/hotel-bolivar.jpg'],
    "price" : "1596"
    },
    ... // other hotel elements go here.
]);
```

Finally, do the following to retrieve a single hotel from the collection:

```
const hotel = await Hotel.findOne({});
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Yes man thankful!! , i wanna understand the await before that use Hotel.create, i know that i need any global function for add async o can you explain this?
Again thousand thanks.